# Cropping white margins in document preview

Tags: margins

I am working on a document using the `book` class, with the default font size of `10pt` and default margins.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I usually use Overleaf, or MiKTeX when the connection is shaky. Now, the "style" that I'm using is indeed the style that I want my final document to be in.

However, in the meantime, since I am on a 15" screen, I could really do away with those large white margins and have a better preview.

Just setting very thin margins with `geometry` is not what I'm looking for. I only want to crop the margins in the PDF preview, without changing the way the text looks.

The `preview` package with option `\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}` is very close to what I'm aiming for, but only "in principle" since it always outputs a single page, which is not what I want.

I can try to explain it better if what I've said so far makes little sense, so do let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the current width/height in the geometry options:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[textwidth=\textwidth,textheight=\textheight,
            paperwidth=\dimexpr\textwidth+1cm,
            paperheight=\dimexpr\textheight+1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\the\textwidth \quad \the\textheight

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. I have further reduced `paperwidth` and increased `paperheight` to `+2.5cm` so that headings and page numbers are also shown. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The package [geometry](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf) provides option to set text height, text width and margins. For example:

```
\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in},
top=1mm, left=1mm,right=1mm, bottom=1mm]{geometry}
```

This sets `textwidth=6.5in` and `textheight=8.75in` and margins to `1mm`. One can adjust the margin to required amount keeping the *text area* constant. The page size will be adjusted accordingly.